# How to split multiple overlapping points in ArcMap 9.2?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.2

I am using ArcGIS (ArcMap with Info license) 9.2. I have many points that have the same XY coordinates. Is there any method to apply any sort of buffer by which they'll get desegregated at different coordinates??

Comment: you can disperse points with an extension in arcview (Point Dispersion Wizard) . unfortunately ArcGIS 9.2 and 9.3 does not have a tool to disperse points at different coordinates permanently .